# Some files are set as "application/octet-stream" type

Tags: php, mime-types

I have weird problem, that when I try to upload different files, some of them are recognized correctly, but some are not and are set as `application/octet-stream` when you check their type `$_FILES['file_1']['type']`

```
Debug Objects: png
Debug Objects: image/png
Debug Objects: php
Debug Objects: application/octet-stream
Debug Objects: rar
Debug Objects: application/octet-stream
Debug Objects: psd
Debug Objects: application/octet-stream
```

I contacted my hosting company, they told me its not an error on their side and that it might be related to CloudFlare, but I never had such problem before.

I know that RAR has `application/octet-stream` as one of possible mime types, but not PHP or PSD.

Those are types for PSD:

```
application/x-photoshop
image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
```

And those are for PHP:

```
application/x-httpd-php
application/php
application/x-php
text/php
text/x-php
application/x-httpd-php-source
```

Does somebody have idea why its doing this? I tried it in IE, FireFox, Chrome and Opera. Happens in all of those browsers.

Is there better way of checking for types? As the ones I am checking are sent by browser, which can be spoofed (I am also checking for extensions for more security). I know there is way to do it with java, but I would like to use PHP and do it server side.

Thanks.

Comment: I think its from Chorme only, have u tried with FF to check the mime type.

Comment: @SudipPal Tried IE, Chrome, FF, Opera. Happens in all of them.

Comment: It's rather unclear what you're asking. What files are recognised as what where when uploading what from where to whom?

Comment: @deceze There is a list of some (not all) files which have their type set to ``application/octet-stream`` instead of propper type. And you obviously also missed that I'm using browser to upload a form in PHP... Try to read it again.

Comment: *"some of them are recognised correctly"* – recognised when where by what? Yes, you're uploading files, but then where exactly are you taking that MIME type from?

Comment: @deceze ``$_FILES['file_1']['type']``

Comment: All the info in `$_FILES` comes from the browser. The server doesn't recognise anything, it merely gives you the data the browser sent.

Comment: @deceze I know about that, if you read my question propperly, you would also know that. I am asking why its doing that and if there is other way of recognising type, without relying on browser or java.

Comment: Look at the top suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+detect+mime+type

Comment: @deceze I was trying some of them, but I cant install any new things on my server as its not my machine, so finding something that was already there and works was a bit hard.

Comment: To be quite frank, you should have focused your question on that then instead of that long preamble about CloudFlare et al.

Comment: @deceze I just wanted to give you all info I had, to not post bad question that would just get downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the mime type on server side with [finfo_file](https://php.net/manual/de/function.finfo-file.php) or [finfo_buffer](https://php.net/manual/de/function.finfo-buffer.php).

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. As I cnat really install anything on my server, it was hard to find something that was already installed there, this is the solution for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Improving on @take answer, i use `file_get_contents()` as well

```
 $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
 print_r($finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($filename)));
```

Answer (score 0):

['type'] is not trustable. An ok solution is http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php